# Do optional elements break RAII and if yes what is a better approach?

Tags: c++, pointers, raii

I have a 2-dimensional matrix of cells. Usually only invisible algorithms work with these cells. But sometimes I want to visualize each cell so I added a pointer to a graphical object

```
class Cell
{
   ...
   QAbstractGraphicsItem* representation_;
   ...
}
```

The constructor of Cell sets representation_ to 0. Sometimes another Visualization class iterates on the matrix and adds elements to Cells that visualize the content of each cell by colors.

**I think this breaks the RAII paradigma. Do you have a better approach?**

I could create another 2-dimensional matrix and from there link to the original matrix so that the pointers are on the visualization side but I would need two matrices then.

Comment: Which part of RAII do you consider broken here?

Comment: The representation_ member is 0 most of the time and is not initialized.

Comment: I think this breaks the MVC paradigm more than it does the RAII paradigm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAII is misnamed, as (I think) Scott Meyers points out.

It shouldn't be called "Resource Acquisition is Initialization", it should be called "Destruction is Resource Release". But we are where we are.

If the Cell "owns" the object pointed to by `representation_`, and deletes it in its destructor, then this is still a form of RAII, the same way that you can initialize a `shared_ptr` with a null pointer, then later set it to something else. I assume you use it correctly (ensure that the object is saved to some Cell or other immediately after it is created, with no chance of failure between the completion of the constructor and the storing of the pointer somewhere it will be eventually freed). If so, you're using the important part of RAII, even though it's not a constructor doing the work.

It's probably a violation of the single responsibility principle. You've made Cell responsible for representing a cell, and *also* for memory-managing this `QAbstractGraphicsItem` object. It would probably simplify things to change `representation_` to a smart pointer type, so there's no need for any special code in the destructor of Cell.

If the Cell doesn't "own" the object pointed to by `representation_`, then that doesn't inherently violate RAII either, it just doesn't implement it. Something else will have to be responsible for ownership of the object. Maybe that other thing uses RAII, maybe it violates it. For the thing to ensure the object lives as long as the Cell needs it, it would have to be involved somehow in the lifecycle of the Cell (for instance, if it owns the cell then you might be fine). So if it isn't, there's a good chance it's violating RAII somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the [**Visitor** design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: The visitor pattern works well for situations where you have a limited number of items and an unlimited number of ways to draw/represent them. The classic visitor though adds extensibility in one direction but removes it from the other.

Comment: After reading the article on wikipedia I think its way to complicated for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're breaking *RAII* (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization) at all, as long as your Cell destructor actually deletes the QAbstractGraphicsItem object (its destructor is virtual, right?) if one is there.  However, you appear to be concerned about the potential *coupling* between your graphics items and cells in this architecture.

Yes, it's attractive to completely separate the object store from its presentation.  The perfect tool for this (as pointed out by Ben Voigt) is something that lets you extend your class definition, from outside the class, with an extra data element.  But C++ doesn't support this.  Your suggestion to keep another matrix for the visualization pointers is the best I can think of, but then you have to maintain this second data structure.  If you don't want to do this, you're going to need to sacrifice this perfect separation for practical simplicity.

Assuming you only have one visualization active at any time, I don't see a problem with keeping a single pointer in your Cells for use by the visualization system.  Your code is fine as-is.  Yes, you are tying together the data storage and presentation, but it's a pretty loose link.  Your cells still don't depend on anything relating to presentation, other than recognizing that the layer exists and might want to store some (opaque) Cell-specific data.

To address other suggestions, the visitor pattern is useful for designing the visualizers, but that's an orthogonal design point.  What if those visitors need to store extra data per-cell?  That's the real question.  As for simulating a property extensions with a map, it's complicated, and it's also not necessary unless you have multiple visualizations operating concurrently on a single matrix.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would like to accept yours too but can only chose one.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are wanting extension properties, perhaps holding color information that isn't needed by `Cell` or the matrix algorithms.  It's a very dynamic-languagy approach.

The usual approach for static languages like C++ would be to subclass `Cell`.  Your algorithms should work just fine on a matrix of `CellSubclass`, although it complicates matters a little bit if you were storing elements sequentially by value in an array.  You can continue doing that and templatize your algorithms, or you can store pointers in the array.

If you really want extension properties, though, you can use a `map<void*,IPropertyValue*>` inside `Cell`, where `IPropertyValue` simply provides a virtual destructor so that you don't leak the extension property values when freeing a `Cell`.  You'll need to cast when retrieving the value.  Use the address of some private static variable as the key, to guarantee uniqueness and uniformity.

EDIT: If you only want/need to store one pointer, then the way you have will work well.  But use a smart pointer, and use `swap` when assigning it.  That way everything will be RAII.

Comment: This seems overly complicated. Is there a more detailed description available?

Comment: The second paragraph is interesting. Isn't this a good use case for multiple inheritance here ? I mean an abstract class `IVisualizable`, and `class VisualizableCell : public Cell, public IVIsualizable`. Then your algorithms act on `Cell`s, and your visualizer acts on `IVisualizable`. Now, if you aren't storing cells by pointers, you have to go with template algorithms, because the size of a Cell object is now unknown.

Answer (score 0):

It does break RAII- you should use a self-releasing pointer.